# Formatting and Indentation of Comments

Tags: formatting

Is there a way to force/control indentation in a multiline comment within an INPUT CELL?

I often end up with some random indentation like the following. I know if I move the comment to a different cell and change the display type (e.g., to CODE) there are less issues but I like to keep the comments in the INPUT cell with the related code for ease of use.

```
ref = Import["reference.dat", "Table"]\[Transpose];
Dimensions[ref]
meas = Import["measure.dat", "Table"]\[Transpose];
Dimensions[meas]
(*
  day1 = 3432000
       day2 = 3312000
         day3 = 3312000
            day4 = 3264000
           day5 = 3312000
    day6 = 3312000
*)
```

Comment: You could try using `\[NewLine]` instead of return at the end of each line. On a mac, this character can be entered using `Ctrl Option Return`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes, there is a very simple way to gain complete control over indentation in comments.**

Just get into the habit of starting every comment with

```
(*"
```

rather than

```
(*
```

Then you can indent to your heart's content using space characters at the start of a line. If you don't want to indent at all, don't use any. Problem solved!

Comment: This is brilliant - a one-character solution to an irritating problem :-)

Comment: Perfect. Confirmed that this works for me.